# Single- vs Multi-Column Index for optimized database performance

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb, primary-key, composite-primary-key

In my database (RDBMS: MariaDB 10.3), I have a table of the following structure:

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+--..
|  ID  |  user_1  |  user_2  |  info_1  |  info_2  |  info_3  |  ..  |  ..
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+--..
```

In the application using the table, I have to query for records as follows:

A) query in f(`ID`);
meaning `WHERE ID = id_value`

B) query in f(`users`),
meaning `WHERE user_1 = value_user_1 AND user_2 = value_user_2 OR user_1 = value_user_2 AND user_2 = value_user_1`

C) query as stated in A) or B) and where any of the additional columns `info_1`, `info_2`, and `info_3`, or a subset of them together, match a given value, meaning for example `WHERE ID = id_value AND info_1 = value_info_1 AND info_2 = value_info_2`, for a query of type C) starting with A) (you may deduce the other scenario for query of type C) starting with B)).

What I want to achieve: For all of the three query types A) B) and C), I want to avoid full  table scans, and be as efficient as possible, as the table may grow really fast upon publication of the app. So, I guess, ideally `EXPLAIN SELECT **anything** FROM my_table` while selecting according to A) B) or C) should return a type of `const` or `eq_ref` according to [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/), if possible.

What I tried:

- define `ID` as the only primary key of the table. Returns `const` query type for A), okay, but the problem for this is that B) queries, or C) queries that start with the user-query of B), both result in full-table scans.
- defined a multi-column index of all three fields (`ID`, `user_1`, `user_2`). Returns `ref` query type for A) with `ref_type` = `const` in the resulting explain table, but again results in full table scans in the same cases as described above ( B) or C) starting with B) ).
- defined `user_1` and `user_2` as single `users` column of datatype JSON, containing a `JSON_ARRAY` of `value_user_1` and `value_user_2`. My thought for this was to avoid the necessity of the `OR` clause as stated in B), and simply query if the array in the `users` column contains both `value_user_1` and `value_user_2`. Then defined composite key (`ID`, `users`). Still the exact same result (using `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(users,JSON_ARRAY(alue_user_1,value_user_2))` ).

How can I get index-based queries / avoid full table scans for all three scenarios A) , B), and C)?

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` _must_ be unique.  It _sounds_ like `ID` is the desired PK.  There can be only one PK.  Once you have `WHERE id = 123`, additional clauses can't do further filtering (other than to eliminate the one row found).

Comment: Thx buddy for ur careful replies here and on DBA.What you're saying also goes for FULLTEXT INDEX searches, right? Meaning that when I make a fulltext search condition with ```MATCH...AGAINST``` in the ```WHERE``` clause and then add further conditions to eliminate among the found rows (max. about 10), this should not significantly slow down the query right? Just because a user said that on DBA, and I don't really understand why that should be the case..?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said over there.  (And I should have chastised you for cross-posting.)  Please provide links between that Question and this so that others (over 30 so far) can get the complete picture.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

- Put the PRIMARY KEY on ID, as you suggest in your first option. This allows you to do direct index seeks when filtering by ID
- Also put a non-clustered index on User_1 and User_2 - this allows you to do (two) index seeks for your queries of type B.

For type C (based on B), it does mean that the query will (can) start with the index to find the relevant rows, then go back to the table to read the rest of the data (e.g., info_1, info_2).

- Uou may want to also include info_1, info_2 and info_3 into the non-clustered index
- This will help with queries of type C based on B, while making index maintenance and other tasks including the index a bit slower.
- I'd suggest trying without these additional columns then only add if necessary.

Comment: I tried so too, but the problem here is that, in queries of type B), the index seek which includes the ```OR``` clause results in a full table scan (I always need to test both possibilities because its all about the pairing of users, so ```user_value_1```  may be the value of ```user_1``` or of ```user_2```, and ```user_value_2``` then will be the value of the not-used column. So this is still using full table scans as soon as I include the OR in B).

Comment: My sample table contains three records at the moment. Same (full table scans for queries B) as written in my question with ```OR```) happens when I use one column ```users``` with for example ```user_value_1,user_value_2``` as the value. I'm starting to think that the engine may uses full table scans for these cases because my sample table is small..? Or does it just generally use full table scans when you include an ```OR``` inside the ```WHERE``` clause with indexes only???

Comment: One way to get around that is to do the query as a UNION (or UNION ALL) e.g., `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_1 = value_user_1 AND user_2 = value_user_2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_1 = value_user_2 AND user_2 = value_user_1`. And yes, if the table is small, it will just do a full table scan.

Comment: I thought that the optimizer decides to do a full table scan as long as the table is so small, but your code using ```UNION ALL``` did indeed result in an indexed search for B) with ```OR```! Still, given that only one of the pairings of ```user_value_1``` and ```user_value_2``` will find a record, if one is found, I may get "```Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const table...```" (```WHERE``` clauses which do not find any record in the table) from 1 - 2 times each time the query is fired. Guess that's the best I can get? Or can you code multi-column indexes with independent order?

Comment: The UNION ALL will make it into two separate queries. However, given they're doing index seeks, it will still be very fast. Once you get many more test cases it's worth testing it without the UNION ALL - but note that even then it will do two seeks (one for each option because of the OR), so the UNION ALL will probably fundamentally be doing the same thing.

Comment: ... while performing better because it will be using indexed searches both times, do I get it right? Cheers buddy!

Comment: Additional question: I found out about FULLTEXT indexes in mariadb, which suddenly allowed index searches like ```WHERE users LIKE '%user_value_1%'``` without returning a syntax error (returns all the records where ```user_value_1``` is one of the users' values, without needing the ```OR``` clause / an additional ```SELECT``` query). However, still does it by full table scans. Are you experienced with how to use fulltext indexes to avoid full table scans..?

Comment: Okay, got it working with the syntax ```EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE MATCH(users) AGAINST('%user_value_1%') ```. Yet, this returns, via the ```EXPLAIN``` output, a ```type``` of ```fulltext```, and a ```ref``` of nothing (empty string), but ```row``` value is 1. Does this actually perform better than your ```UNION``` suggestion..?

Comment: for details, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280533/query-data-via-username-pair-best-performance